# Is there a fast algorithm to merge sorted B+Trees?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I'm writing a dbm style database manager with immutable B+Trees as the storage medium (see http://sf.net/projects/aodbm/ ). Is there a fast algorithm for merging two B+Trees (where the trees potentially share nodes)?

Comment: Is it the case that the maximum key of tree `A` is less or equal than the minimum key of tree `B`. If so, it is really fast, otherwise I think you will have to employ a more sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: @phimuemue, unfortunately that's only the case in extremely contrived cases.

Answer (score 1):

it is omega(n) problem.

proof: assume it had better complexity O(d) and d < n. you can arrange a B+ tree as an array, and then merging the two trees will be merging two arrays. if so, you could do merge(A1,A2) in O(d), and using mergesort could be O(dlog(n)) - contradiction.

a O(n) solution (actually it will be of course theta(n)):

1.flat T1 and T2 into sorted arrays A1,A2. 

2.use A <- merge(A1,A2)

3. build an empty "almost full" tree T with exactly |T1|+|T2| 'places'. 

4. fill in T with A (in-order search)

5. result is T.

complexity:

step 1 is O(n) (in order search)

step 2 is O(n) merge`s complexity (since A1,A2 are both sorted)

steps 3+4 are trivially O(n) as well

Comment: Yes, except that the trees may share nodes. In this case, the children of the shared nodes don't have to be iterated over, so it's possible that an algorithm exists that is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes that are not shared and have parents that have children that are shared.

Comment: in what complexity can you find a shared node given two trees?

Comment: @amit, That's a question I hoped someone would be able to answer. I have an idea where it may be possible to do a breadth-first-search on both trees in tandem in which case it's `O(n)` where `n` is the number of unshared nodes.

Comment: @dan are shared nodes also share all their children? because if it is not the case, then even if you do manage to sort in O(n) where n is unshared nodes, you will need to manipulate somehow each and every one of the shared nodes - so their sub-trees will also be sorted, which will be O(|V|-n), and you will get back to O(n). or am I missing something? about finding the shared nodes - I cannot think of a better way then BFS (nor a proof there is none)

Comment: @amit, yes, the actual node is shared, as in it's pointers to the same location.

Comment: @dan, so what about finding the set of shared ROOTS and collapse them into single nodes (give them a mark so the merging algorithm will 'think' they are leaves) it should work (I think) because they are both the same, so every element which is bigger/smaller then the subtree in T1, will also be bigger then it in T2. now you can do it in O(n+r) where n is the number of nonshared nodes, and r is the number of shared ROOTS (which is O(n), since it's B+ tree) so you can get O(n).

Comment: @amit, if you modify your answer to incorporate this then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @dan the problem with my suggestion (noticed it while editing) is that the result tree will be deeper, its height will actually be O(logn + h) where h deepest common tree's height (because we add a tree with height h to a logn tree...) in the average case it will be just fine (since n is the number of non shared nodes), but at some cases it could increase the tree's height. also: it would require manually adding leaves to the tree (to do this in O(1) you will need pointers to the smallest and biggest elements, since every element you will add is bigger or smaller then the sub-tree.

Comment: @amit, we need some way of making the non-shared roots be at approximately the same height as they were in the trees before.

Comment: after giving it some thought, I think I'm stuck... I cannot prove it cannot be done, but it certainly seems so (of course, I might be wrong). Unless you got some other direction for it (which I'll be glad to bounce ideas on) - it seems it's an engineering trade-off one must make.

Comment: @amit, The idea I've got is that first you find the change-set that when applied to T1 would give you T2. Then remove all of the remove operations from the change-set. Then apply the change-set to T1. Naively, I think this would be `O(c log n)`, where c is the number of changes and n is the size of the trees.